# Anyone know how to turn on USB debugging "ON" on Nexus Q without running the Q app on smartphone?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

Anyone know how to turn on USB debugging "ON" on Nexus Q without running the Q app on smartphone?

I could not succeed to configure from Nexus Q app running on my smartphone, it starts with "Couldn't sign in: An error occurred while attempting to sign in....".
During powercycle, i tapped LED button on very specific time, which occationally turns to RED led, but I don't think it turns on USB debugging ON because $adb devices returns empty list.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer.

Sometime over the summer, Google turned off the Nexus Q servers, so you can no longer authenticate the Nexus Q app, which is what is used to turn on debug mode.

There is an image that can be flashed to the device, in fastboot mode, that has adb (debug) mode enabled by default.

I followed these steps last night and it all worked flawlessly.  Here is a link that has the steps and the links to the needed downloads.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2408799

To get debug mode enabled follow these steps:  (the following comes from the post on the XDA Developers Forum)

---

### To fastboot unlock your device / Credit and thanks to -> fiveipads

1. cmd to platform-tools
2. Reboot to the bootloader -> cover your Q with your hand -> power on nexus Q as

soon as you see red remove your hand -> (will go solid red and you are in

bootloader)

1. Unlock your device* (with fastboot tool) (type) -> fastboot oem unlock

(immediately copy and paste this into tool and hit enter you have only 5 secs) ->

fastboot oem unlock_accept

4.Q will reboot and turn purple etc.

5.Unplug Q and restart in bootloader see #2. (type) -> fastboot getvar unlocked

(this verifies you unlocked your Q->should reply->unlocked:yes)IF NOT DO NOT

PROCEED TILL IT DOES.

---

### Load a unsecure boot image with adb enabled / Credit and thanks to -> ObsidianX

1.Download -> http://forum.xda-developers.com/atta...2&d=1355508721

2.This is a modified boot.img from the factory Nexus Q images that enables adb

debugging on boot in root mode.->Test before you flash!

3.Put the file you download into you platform-tools folder(make sure no other

images have the same name in that folder)

4.Flash the image -> (type in fastboot) -> fastboot flash boot boot-root.img

(image will write should say ok and writing boot etc.)

5.Pull the power on your q and restart the Q

Answer (score -1):

To see the option for USB debugging mode in Nexus 4 or Android 4.2 or higher OS, do the following:

Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the Menu button while on your home screen and tapping “System settings”
Now scroll to the bottom and tap “About phone” or “About tablet”.
At the “About” screen, scroll to the bottom and tap on “Build number” seven times.

Make sure you tap seven times. If you see a “Not need, you are already a developer!” message pop up, then you know you have done it correctly.
Done! By tapping on “Build number” seven times, you have unlocked USB debugging mode on Android 4.2 and higher. You can now enable/disable it whenever you desire by going to “Settings” -> “Developer Options” -> “Debugging” ->” USB debugging”.